# Notepad++ auto complete delete

Tags: notepad++

Is there a way in Notepad++ to auto delete quotes, brackets, parentheses, and curly brackets? For example, in Pycharm if you have a set of double quotes (or brackets, braces, etc) and you delete one of the quotes, the other quote is deleted as well. (same thing for brackets, braces, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't appear that this is currently possible with the Auto-Insert feature as it exists today.

Documentation:
http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Auto_Completion#Auto-insertion

I think it is a worthy enhancement request, I've posted the question on the Notepad++ forums:

https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/11402/delete-auto-inserted-character-on-delete-of-typed-character